# What is the C++ memory layout of objects/structs etc?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

In C++ I presume the C++ standard has nothing to do with how data members are arranged within a class, in terms of memory layout? Would I be right in thinking this is down to the compiler in question?

I'm very interested in learning how objects and other C++ entities (structs etc) are represented in physical memory (I know things like lists are node to node and arrays are continuous memory- but all the other aspects to the language).

**EDIT: Would learning x86 assembler help with this and understanding C++ better?**

Comment: probably shortest answer to your question is fields of struct or classes are represented as contiguous in memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the standard doesn't say how the objects are to be represented in memory. To get an idea how normall C++ objects are represented read this book: [inside C++ object model.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201834545)

Comment: The standard does specify *some* things about how objects are to be represented in memory. But you're right that there's also a lot it doesn't specify

Answer (score 6):

The C++ standard does specify a few things, but far from everything.

The main rules are these:

- objects in an array are laid out contiguously, with no padding between them.
- class member objects *not* separated by an access specifier (`public:`/`private:`/`protected:`) are laid out in memory in the order in which they're declared, but there may be an unspecified amount of padding between member objects.
- for certain types (standard-layout structs, in standardese terminology), the first base class, or if none exists, the first member, is laid out at the same address that the class itself.

There are a few more bits and pieces specified by the standard, but on the whole, the remaining details are really down to the compiler.

Comment: I have a small question, if I have a class with, say 10 member functions. Would it be known that accessing the 10th-declared function would be slower than the 1st? Is this down to the order they are declared in the header file?

Comment: The C++ standard doesn't really say anything about that, but in any sane compiler, it makes no difference. Member functions are not represented in the object at all. At compile-time, the compiler determines which function to call, so it doesn't need to look inside the object at all at runtime.

Comment: @NicolBolas: source, please? 9.2:12 specifies point 2, at least, and applies to any "non-union class". Perhaps you should check the standard before correcting and downvoting others? If you're unsure, it is actually allowed to post a comment asking for verification before you downvote. For point 3, you may be right, and I'll fix my answer to reflect that

Comment: @jalf +1 helping should still be rewarded

Comment: @OliverStutz: well, techincally, it's not much of a help if it provides incorrect information, so I appreciate being corrected. ;) But before downvoting, I think it's fair to ask that you actually ensure that you're correct, and that the person you're downvoting is not

Comment: By the way, I finally found it in the standard: @NicolBolas was correct on point 3, as specified by 9.2:18. I've updated the answer with this information. On point 2, my answer was, as far as I can see, correct. And I'd appreciate a citation if he has information to the contrary

Comment: @jalf: Fair enough. Since you can't rely on the layout for non-standard layout types, I assumed the spec defined them as unspecified.

Comment: @NicolBolas: technically you can't rely on the layout of standard-layout types either. Things like padding are still unspecified. But yeah, the layout of non-standard-layout types is even *less* reliable :)

Comment: @jalf: "Rely on" as in "know that any two types with the equivalent layout are compatible". Not as in "know the byte offsets of"; that's what `offsetof` is for.