# Making sense of non-primitive data types

Tags: c++, types, computer-science

Understanding how primitive data types works is easy: Everything in a computer is stored as a series of 0s and 1s, and so everything I need to store needs to be encoded as a series of 0s and 1s. For example: the real number `3.14` must be stored as a bit pattern, the negative number `-1234` must be stored as a bit pattern, the character `'A'` must be stored as a bit pattern, etc. When I store one of these data in memory, I have to mark the memory location of where they're stored with a specific data type (e.g. `float` for a bit pattern that represents a real number), this data type tells me how to interpret this bit pattern when I ask for it later.

But how this definition applies to something like a class, I mean when I create an object of a specific class, for example:

```
MyClass mc;
```

`mc` does not store a bit pattern that needs to be interpreted in a specific way, how to make sense of considering a class to be a data type? Or is there's another definition for a data type?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the C++ memory layout of objects/structs etc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12884933/what-is-the-c-memory-layout-of-objects-structs-etc)

Comment: `mc` does indeed refer to a bit pattern that needs to be interpreted in a specific way.

Answer (score 0):

A class or struct is a composition of other data types - a composite data type - where the constituent data types may be either primitive or composite data types.

In the following example scenario, `X` and `Y` are two composite data types. `Y` is defined only in terms of primitive data types. `X` is defined in terms of primitive data types and `Y`.

```
struct Y
{
    double* d;
    char e;
}

struct X
{
    float a;
    int b;
    Y c;
}
```

The compiler decides how it is going to define the bit patterns for `X` and `Y`. For example, `Y` might look like this:

```
<8 bytes for double* d><1 byte for char e>
```

And `X` might look like this:

```
<4 bytes for float a><4 bytes for int b><9 bytes for Y c>
```

The particular bit pattern the compiler chooses for each class or struct is not important to know for understanding the concept. What's important is that the compiler picks a particular bit pattern for each class or struct and then consistently uses that everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

A class and other composite data types are usually stored with their members only.  The bit content would depend on the values of their data members.

So given the following class:

```
class MyClass
{
  bool  flag;
  int   number;
  double d;
};
```

The computer would store the 1s and 0s for the `flag` member, followed by some padding (skipping bytes), followed by the 1s and 0s for the `number` field, followed by more padding, then followed by the 1s and 0s for the `d` field.